# UIViewController takes too long to deallocate and blocks UI in UINavigationController

Tags: ios, user-interface, memory-management, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

UIViewControllers are deallocated on the main thread.
([Why is UIViewController deallocated on the main thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32006565/why-is-uiviewcontroller-deallocated-on-the-main-thread))

My UINavigationController has a UIViewController which is very memory-heavy (SceneKit Scene with thousands of nodes).

When User pushes back button, this UIViewController gets dismissed.

However, UI gets blocked for around 4 seconds until deallocation finishes.

How can I avoid the UI getting blocked while deallocation completes?

Or, how can I be notified when deallocation finished, so I can show a spinner while the UI is blocked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved with the answer I got to this other question: [Heavy SceneKit scene in UINavigationViewController takes too long to dealloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43553312/heavy-scenekit-scene-in-uinavigationviewcontroller-takes-too-long-to-dealloc)